# how to get rid of warning related to : indexForInsertingObject:sortedUsingBlock:

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have the following line of code:

```
 int insertIdx = (int)[self.itemsToDisplay indexForInsertingObject:item sortedUsingBlock:^(id a, id b) {
        MWFeedItem *item1 = (MWFeedItem *) a;
        MWFeedItem *item2 = (MWFeedItem *) b;
        return [item1.date compare:item2.date];
    }];
```

but XCode gives me the following warning on it:

```
NSMutableArray' may not respond to '-indexForInsertingObject:sortedUsingBlock:
```

how to get rid of this warning ? and could I know where excatly this method is defined in the SDK ?
thanks so much in advance ...

Comment: Is this itemsToDisplay a normal NSMutableArray or one that you made extending the NSMutableArray?

Comment: @dragon112 yes it's a normal NSMutableArray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-indexForInsertingObject:sortedUsingBlock:` is not part of the official, public SDK. Since it looks like you haven’t declared and implemented a category on `NSMutableArray` that contains that method, you could write one based on [this blog post by Jayway Team](http://blog.jayway.com/2009/03/28/adding-sorted-inserts-to-uimutablearray/). Having done that, it’s just a matter of importing the header file that declares the category.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it has worked for me and the warning has been suppressed. but I wonder how did that method worked without problems at run time although it's not defined in the SDK, does that mean it's been defined in some of the header files in my project (I have alot of these .h files imported) ?

Comment: If it works at runtime, it’s either a private method in the SDK or a category that’s part of your project. Try searching for `@interface NSArray` and `@interface NSMutableArray` in all your project files.

Comment: yup, I found it in one of the files ... thank you for your kind help :)

Answer (score 1):

to disable the warnings for one file add this:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wwarning-flag"
```

It should ignore all warnings. The problem is however you will not see any warnings in that file. even if they are legit.